# Having 2 console outputs show at the same time when separated by an input

Tags: c++, console-application

I'm trying to create a simple login page in c++.  Currently, in my program you have to enter the username before the password input becomes available. I want to be able to show both and have the option to input one before the other.

```
cout << "User:  "; cin >> enteruser;
cout << "Pass:  "; cin >> enterpass;

return 0;
```

I want it to be similar to a web login page, but in a c++ console application window.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for the kinds of console manipulation provided by the _ncurses_ library.  More specific advice will depend on what operating system you are targeting.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709605/libraries-for-displaying-a-text-mode-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ncurses way is something like:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

char userFieldText = "User: ";
char passFieldText = "Pass: ";
char inputUserName[100];
char inputPass[100];
int rowCount;
int columnCount;

initscr();
getmaxyx(stdscr,rowCount,columnCount);
mvprintw(1,1,"%s",userFieldText);
mvprintw(2,1,"%s",passFieldText);
getstr(inputUserName);          // Get input until enter
getstr(inputPass);          // Get input until enter
endwin();
```

Paraphrased from [ncurses docs](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/scanw.html), see this link if you want further descriptions on their library functions. You get some convenience functions that help you traverse the console with something like **ncurses**. Not as creative as plain C++, but depends if you want more features out of a library like it down the road.

Comment: Thanks, I was always wondering if there was a library for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic implementation without using any library and just using escape sequences defined at http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php to set the cursor position.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

void cursor_up(int lines)
{
    /* Enter escape sequence */
    printf("%c%c%dA", 0x1b, 0x5b, lines);
}

void cursor_forward(int cols)
{
    /* Enter escape sequence */
    printf("%c%c%dC", 0x1b, 0x5b, cols);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string username;
    std::string passwd;

    std::string user_prompt = "Enter user: "; 
    std::string passwd_prompt = "Enter password: ";

    std::cout << user_prompt << std::endl;
    std::cout << passwd_prompt << std::endl;

    cursor_up(2);
    cursor_forward(user_prompt.length());
    std::cin >> username;

    cursor_forward(passwd_prompt.length());
    std::cin >> passwd;

    return 0;
}
```